# Train spacy model using custom input

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

This is my first try with spacy.
I have a spacy training data which is of following form.

```
[
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"Michael",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"U-PER"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"Irwin",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"U-PER"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"Jordan",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"U-PER"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"is",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"an",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"American",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"scientist",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"Professor",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"at",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"the",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"University",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"U-ORG"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"of",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"U-ORG"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"California",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"U-ORG"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"Berkeley",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"U-LOC"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"and",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"a",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"researcher",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"in",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"machine",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"learning",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"statistics",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"and",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"artificial",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"intelligence",
                "tag":"-",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "orth":"",
                "tag":"",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

All the examples  sofar  I have seen to train a spacy model (https://spacy.io/usage/training#spacy-train-cli)  is work with following type of input
[image]

Can some one please show an example to train a sapcy input of the first form

Answer (score 1):

I recently updated the IOB/NER converters and created a set of example inputs accepted by `spacy convert -c iob` with the corresponding training data output in this format:

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/8ebc3711dc1ec065c39aeb6017d9ace129a28d3f/examples/training/ner_example_data

The updated converters will be in the next release, but if you want to try it out sooner you can install the master branch from source.

Comment: Thanks. I could see that https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/8ebc3711dc1ec065c39aeb6017d9ace129a28d3f/examples/training/training-data.json is of the desired form and https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/8ebc3711dc1ec065c39aeb6017d9ace129a28d3f/examples/training/ner_multitask_objective.py uses it. I will give a try.

Comment: Do you have a time line for next release?

Comment: one more thing, I could read form the comments of https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/8ebc3711dc1ec065c39aeb6017d9ace129a28d3f/examples/training/ner_multitask_objective.py that it's "Developed and tested for spaCy 2.0.6". The version which I installed is 2.1.8. Should not be it in already?

Comment: Everything is ramping up for 2.2 and it should be soon, but I don't know exactly when. That training script isn't related to the format converters, which are run from `spacy convert`. The spacy training format hasn't changed, just the converters from other common IOB/NER formats to the spacy training format used with `spacy train`. If you look at the details in the training loop `TRAIN_DATA` is not in the same format in the NER multitask script as `TRAIN_DATA` in the `train_ner.py` script. (This is confusing and inconsistent. Hopefully there will be a better training format at some point.)

Comment: I am confused. Let me ask couple of questions.Is there a difference between the .json format shown in https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/8ebc3711dc1ec065c39aeb6017d9ace129a28d3f/examples/training/ner_example_data/ner-token-per-line.json and my first json format? If it's not could you please show a sample script to train using such fomat

Comment: There is the format with text organized into `"paragraphs"` and annotation on each word as a token, which is typically called the spacy training format because it's used with the CLI train command `python -m spacy train`. The other format (the second example in the original question) is typically a list of `(text_string, annotation_dict)` tuples and it's used in a lot of example scripts because it's a lot more compact for span annotations like entities where you don't need to provide labels for each individual word.